# gltfpack issue - text position is wrong

Tags: gltf

I'm using gltfpack to compress my glb model. It works good, but there is an error with the text, that is stores in the glb file.
It should just be in a normal form, but after compression an laoding again in a gltf viewer, it look like this:
[image]

You can see, the letters "S" and "i" are not in the right position.
I tried some flags to avoid this issue, but nothing helped.

Someone has a clue on how to fix this?

It's quite urgend, due to the live presentation end of the next week.

Thank you very much.

Right text position, got wrong text position

Comment: I would recommend filing a bug with the gltfpack software – there's little Stack Overflow commenters will be able to do to resolve your issue based on a screenshot, with no way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I Already raised an issue and it was confirmed as a bug. It's already fixed and working.